# Как сменить версию php c 5.4 до 7 без отключения сайта? VPS

Tags: php, apache

Apach 2.2, CentOS Linux 6 KVM, до этого устанавливал дома на ubuntu server

Comment: никак. Как минимум апач перегрузить придется

Answer (score 0):

Это не возможно. При обновлении версии apache его необходимо перезагрузить